# How to fill part of shapes in Actionscript

Tags: graphics, actionscript

I want to fill some part of the shapes in actionscript, lets say "half of a circle", but unfortunately i could not find any suitable way to do it ?. Any suggestions will be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

one solution, in your case you have to draw some **Close-region**@ square and rectangle triangle etc. in your Main region and then you can fill it whole part of the region which you draw. so if you want to fill a part of the region then you must draw a region on your main region then you can fill it so user have a feeling that he has filling a half region.

May This link'll be helpfull [the ActionScript Drawing API](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/drawingapi/) & [Drawing and Filling Partial Circles](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/circlefill/)